# Remove underline from TextView which uses Widget.EditText style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, android-styles

I have a `TextView` for showing user's wallet balance in my app. In order to set error indicator on low balance I added Widget.`EditText` style to the `TextView`. My issues is after adding this style, the `TextView` is showing an under line. How can I remove that underline?

My `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hm_bal"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="----"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" />
```

I don't want to change the style since using this theme was perfect for my requirement except the underline.

Comment: set backgroung color transparent

Comment: Have u tried `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `transparent` background in your `textview`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

LIKE

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hm_bal"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="----"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" />
```

Answer (score 1):

set background null

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: i added this , but then .myTextView.getBackground().clearColorFilter(); getting null pointer exception